# C# make class invisible to all namespaces other than its own

Tags: c#, namespaces, visibility

Suppose I have the namespace `Events`, which contains only the classes `EventManager` and `EventType`.

I want `EventType` to be invisible in any other namespace, the only class who should be able to see `EventType` is `EventManager`.

How can I do this? I read something about `Friend` but still don't know it is the right choice.

Comment: There is no access-modifier in c# restricting to a namespace. You can only declare the type as `internal` to restrict visibility to the containing assembly.

Comment: I find your assignment of gender to a class interesting.

Comment: not sure entirely what your going for, but if you make EventType a sub/nested class in event manager you can make it Protected to keep other classes from using it i believe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017778/protected-classes-in-net goes into more detail.

Comment: You can make `EventType` a private class inside the `EventManager` class

Comment: @STLDeveloper: in French I believe it is _"la classe"_ - so feminine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expressed two "wants" in this [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) (at the same time) statement:

> I want EventType to be invisible in any other namespace, the only
>   class who should be able to see EventType is EventManager.

For the first part (**X**), as mentioned in the comments, there is no way to limit access to a class to only a single namespace directly in C#. You can kind of get what you want if you make it `internal` and isolate it in an assembly containing *only* that namespace.

That seems like a dubious practice however, and as you go about adding code you'll probably wind up abandoning this approach.

For the second part (**Y**), you can make `EventType` only visible to `EventManager` (*this is your true intent*) like this

```
public class EventManager
{
     private class EventType
     { ... }
}
```

The friend idea comes from C++ by the way.